# Why vundle is not available with apt?

Tags: apt, vim

it seems that all vim plugin around can be managed and installed with a plugin manager. This because:

1. on apt are only available few plugins
2. many plugins have many dependencies
3. and with a plugin manager, search and install a plugin is much more fast and easy

but for example vundle must be manually installed and this can drive the use to a lot of mess under of .vim folder.

- Then why vundle is not available as apt package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most deb packages (that's what apt manages) are created by Debian volunteers.

Apparently, nobody in the vundle user community cared enough to package it.

If you care enough, you can package vundle for Debian, from whence it will flow to all Debian-based distros: Ubuntu, Pop, Arch, Zorin, etc). It's a great way to contribute to the free/open software ecosystem. Start at http://mentors.debian.net.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just that Vundle hasn't been packaged for Debian, but it's also that the philosophy of Vundle (and similar Vim plug-in managers) and Debian/apt for installing packages are the complete opposite of each other.

Vundle downloads packages directly from GitHub into a subdirectory under your home, and gives you commands inside Vim itself to manage and update those packages. The packages you install will be available for your user only. If the author of the package pushes a bug fix, it will be available to you immediately (which also means if they break the package, you'll get the broken version right away as well.)

Debian/apt on the other way take the other approach. They want to install packages system-wide and have the files owned by root, so that users can't overwrite them (accidentally or maliciously.) They want to curate the list of packages that are available (include high quality, popular software.) They track versions very closely and typically don't release whatever is pushed to GitHub immediately, but have it go through testing or unstable repos, so you can be a bit more confident that they might have fewer bugs.

On the upside, the Debian model takes care of packaging tricky plug-ins that need dependencies in other languages such as C built to match the Vim package. YouCompleteMe is a great example of that, it's a pain to install.

Personally, I find that the "roll your own" model of using a Vim plug-in manager such as Vundle or similar is better. If you care enough about Vim to install plug-ins, you'll probably want to experiment, have plug-ins enabled/disabled, try out new plug-ins and niche plug-ins. The Debian model is not really very well suited for that.

Installing Vundle itself is really easy, and having it installed in your personal `.vim` directory in your home directory means you can have it update itself (something that Debian would most likely have to disable if they were to package it, since it would live in a root-owned directory and be managed by dpkg.)

Also consider that Vundle specifically hasn't really been maintained for a few years and there are better alternatives out there. I tend to recommend [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). It uses a very similar model to Vundle, so it should look very familiar to Vundle users. Yet, it's an active project. It has better performance (parallel downloads, sparse checkouts that use less disk space), more features (you can add post-install/post-update hooks to your configuration, for example to build C components of plug-ins) and is much easier to install (just download a single file into a specific location, also a lot less finicky about the order in which you enable options in your vimrc.) Overall, it's a big improvement and yet close enough that it should be very easy to pick it up. I strongly recommend it!